# How do I re-add the messaging indicator?

Tags: 10.10, indicator, panel

I mistakenly removed by message indicator from the panel. How can I add it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the panel, select *Add to Panel*, find the *Indicator Applet* and click add.

[image]